# to create a custom post type with additionnal url field such as link to social network and an email field

Tags: custom-field

I'm a low beginner with wordpress and I have to create a custom post type with additionnal custom fields: link for social network and a field for email address.

the purpose is to have a page with the members of a team and for adding a new member we need to allow him or her to add his or her name, an email address and a her or his profil link for a social network without using a plugin like ACF.

Need some help :-)
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom Post types allow to set custom fields (aka meta-data) capability. Just add `'custom-fields'` capability to your arguments within the array. No need for the plugin just for adding a couple of fields.

```
'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'custom-fields' )
```

Comment: as a low beginner at the time I posted this question, I should have looked well to wordpress codex but we learn from mistake